# Allow Elastice Beanstalk IPs to another EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling, aws-security-group

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk with LB and auto scaling group. 
Also, I have an EC2 machine which should only allow incoming connection from the EB instances. EB and EC2 are in the same VPC.

I have added the EB security group in the EC2 security group inbound. Still, I cannot establish the connection between these machines.
I can successfully make the connection between these machines if I have manually allowed the EB instances IPs to the EC2 SG.

Is there any way to get rid of this manual update? 
How can I make the connection between EC2 and EB?

Comment: Adding an inbound rule from the security group associated with your EB instances should work. Please post your security group settings in detail to help us debug.

Comment: I have added the EB security group as the inbound rule in the EC2 SG.But it is not working